# fastest way to sort database records

Tags: sql, linq, performance, datatable

I have a datatable with approx. 5000 records and put it in a dataset/datatable
what's the fastest way to sort these ?

- By the database ? (SQL Server 2008)
- By the datatable ? dt.Select("", "order by columns");
- LINQ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a real database server, and the database is correctly indexed, the fastest way to do it would be to push the sort down to the database.

If you assume everything is runing on your laptop, I would still take an indexed sort over an in-memory sort(linq).

Comment: i'm developing on my laptop, and have a live server with SQL Server 2008. How can you do an indexed sort in-memory ? (I know I can sort in memory, but not an indexed memory search)

Comment: @Ruutert sorry if I confused you, but I was just stating that if everything was running on your laptop, the indexed database will still be faster.  Since you just stated that you have a live server then I suggest that you leverage the DB Server to do the sort.

Comment: should I put an index on the columns that I want to sort?

Answer (score 1):

I would always perform a sort like this in the database.

Comment: if you sort the records in the database, it's slower than doing it in memory

Comment: I stand by my answer for the reasons better articulated by @Nix.

Comment: @Ruuter, if you think you know the answer, why do you ask. BTW: yes sorting in memory is faster, but (retrieving from db unsorted + sorting in memory) is probably not faster then (retrieving from db sorted) if your db is properly indexed for this task.

Comment: How is it faster if you are comparing an application server sorting in memory to a database server?

Comment: @Jens Schauder ... I don't know the answer .. but there is a lot of information on the internet and I want to discuss it here ... I have to check my indexes ...